# SceneKit's instance property "autoenablesDefaultLighting" doesn't work

Tags: swift, macos, scenekit

I tried to turn on and off default lighting in SCNView via `.autoenablesDefaultLighting` instance property but in doesn't work (Neither in UI nor programmatically).

I need all objects to be black when there's no light.

**How to turn default lighting off**?

Here's a code:

```
import SceneKit
import QuartzCore

class GameViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let scnView = SCNView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, 
                                            y: 0,
                                        width: 450, 
                                       height: 300))

        view.addSubview(scnView)
        scnView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = false     // DOESN'T WORK
        scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
        scnView.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue

        let scene = SCNScene()
        scnView.scene = scene

        let sphereGeo = SCNSphere(radius: 2)
        sphereGeo.segmentCount = 4
        sphereGeo.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = NSColor.lightGray
        let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphereGeo)
        sphereNode.name = "Sphere Node"
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make a dark/low light SceneKit scene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36705733/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-dark-low-light-scenekit-scene)

Comment: My question is about Default Lighting property – not about other Light Fixtures (such as Directional light, Omni, Ambient, etc.)

Comment: These are absolutely different questions.

Comment: What that answer explains is that `autoenablesDefaultLighting = false` has no effect if there are no lights in your scene.

Comment: Yes, there are no lights in my scene, only default lighting that can't be turned off. Check a code, please.

Comment: I have checked your code, there are no lights in your scene so `autoenablesDefaultLighting` has no effect. If you add a light (omni, directional or spot) and set the intensity to 0, or color to black your scene will be dark.

Comment: But I found out that `.autoenablesDefaultLighting = false` does work BUT only with `.physicallyBased` shading model.

Comment: Many 3D authoring tools (like Maya and Houdini) don't need any other lights to be added for turning off default lighting, so I think it's a bug in SceneKit. Especially it does properly work with `.physicallyBased` shading model. So, I reckon my question is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's working only when I'm using `Physically Based Rendering` shading model.

```
let material = SCNMaterial()
material.lightingModel = SCNMaterial.LightingModel.physicallyBased

sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = false
```

If I use `.physicallyBased` type property for shading my models the lighting works as supposed.